# Multicast packets being dropped at IP layer?

Tags: centos, networking, multicast

External multicast data is being received by machine #1 and forwarded to machine #2. On machine #2 I can see the multicast packets being received when I use `tcpdump`, `ethtool` and `netstat -i` (ethernet layer).

However, when I run `netstat -s -u` the number of UDP packets isn't increasing, nor is `InMcastPkts` but `InOctets` is increasing. So my guess is packets are being dropped in the IP or UDP/TCP layer?

How can I confirm this and what would be the most-likely cause of the packet-loss?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any piece of software on machine #2 that do a "IGMP JOIN" on the multicast group ?

The principle of multicast is that you must join the group to get the trafic or it get dropped.

Comment: I have an application which subscribes to the group and listens for packets but it's not receiving any. The app was listening when i ran the commands